# Using getline with ifstream class member

Tags: c++

The compiler error is:

`no matching function for call to 'getline(const ifstream&, std::string&)'`

**StartScreen.h**

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Screen.h"

class StartScreen: public Screen {
public:
    StartScreen();
    virtual ~StartScreen();
    void advise() const;
    void draw() const;
private:
    StartScreen(const StartScreen&) = delete;
    StartScreen& operator=(const StartScreen&) = delete;
    std::ifstream screen_content_;
};
```

**StartScreen.cpp**

```cpp
#include "StartScreen.h"

StartScreen::StartScreen() {
    screen_content_.open("start-screen.txt");
}

StartScreen::~StartScreen() {
    screen_content_.close();
}

void StartScreen::advise() const {
}

void StartScreen::draw() const {
    std::string line;
    if (screen_content_.is_open()) {
        while (screen_content_.eof()) {
            std::getline(screen_content_, line);
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to print all lines from a text file in standard output. Using fstream is the right way? Or there's a better solution?

Comment: Since `draw()` is declared `const` `screen_content_` is also `const` while `getline` takes a non-`const` `ifstream` as its first parameter. Pass a non-`const` instance of `ifstream` and you're good.

Comment: @Captain Make this an answer please. It is!

Comment: @Bledson _"Done"_ what actually??

Comment: Removed `const` from `draw()` declaration. As suggested, declaring `screen_content_` as `mutable` also worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment above says, the problem that `draw()` is declared const.

In a const member function all your member variables are treated as const.

Reading from a stream alters the stream object (it has to fill the stream buffer and update the stream position) so you can't do it on a const stream.

Either make `draw()` non-const, or make `screen_content_` mutable.